# Three20 doesn't show website in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, three20

Hi all
I have a tabbar based application. In one view I have a TTTabStrip with different TTTabItems. Everything works (loading normal UIViewControllers) except loading UIWebViews.

In the app delegate I have set up the url mapping:

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.supportsShakeToReload = YES;
navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;

TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]]; // default klasse wenn nichts anderes gewählt ist.
[map from:@"tt://test" toViewController:[TestController class]];
```

The test controller contains one UIWebView. I can see (NSLog) that the loadView-Method gets called, but the URL is not being opened:

```
- (void) loadView {

    CGRect applicationFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]]; 

    // support zooming
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
```

For instance, I can change the background of the UIWebView to black.

How can I load google in the web view below the TTTabStrip?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following and add the method viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    CGRect applicationFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];

    // support zooming
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [newView addSubview:webView];

    self.view = newView;
    [newView release];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks a lot for your answer. Your loadView method has been called, but the viewWillAppear method has not been touched. That means that the webview is still grey.

Comment: This is strange. Can you put something simple in the view of the TestController, like a label? And then see if it is displayed. viewWillAppear should be called. Maybe viewDidAppear is called? Have you set the frame of the webview?

Comment: You were right. viewDidLoad has been called. I put the content of viewWillAppear into viewDidLoad but nothing happens. The strange thing is when I try to load a simple xib that has been created in IB, then it is shown. There must be something wrong with this webview. No the frame of the webView has not been set..

Comment: I finally got it. I have set the frame of the webView and it workes. I have added these two lines into loadView: CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
 webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame]; Thanks so much Nick, you f***ing saved my life :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Funny thing is how many times you stumble across those simple problems which consume so much time solving.

Comment: Just for completeness, isn't the [newView release] going to create a zombie since it's already autoreleased?

Comment: You are correct, the autorelease should not be there. I'll correct that.